# IdentityServer4 Role Based Authorization for Web API with ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4  with .Net Core 2.1 and Asp.Net Core Identity. I have two projects in my Solution.

- IdentityServer
- Web API

I want to Protect my Web APIs, I use postman for requesting new tokens, It works and tokens are generated successfully. When I use  `[Authorize]` on my controllers without Roles it works perfectly but when I use  `[Authorize(Roles="Student")]` (even with `[Authorize(Policy="Student")]`) it always return `403 forbidden`

Whats wrong with my code

Web API startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Student", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Student")))
            .AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Teacher", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Teacher")))
            .AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Admin")))
            .AddJsonFormatters();

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "api1";
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Test API :

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles="Student")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

IdentityServer startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            string migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;


            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                             options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


            services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            IIdentityServerBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()

                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                        b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                        b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    // options.TokenCleanupInterval = 15; // frequency in seconds to cleanup stale grants. 15 is useful during debugging
                })
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("need to configure key material");
            }

            services.AddAuthentication();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {


          //  InitializeDatabase(app);



            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }



        }
    }
```

IdentityServer4 config.cs

```
   public class Config
    {
        // scopes define the resources in your system
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "My API"),
                 new ApiResource("roles", "My Roles"),
                 new IdentityResource("roles", new[] { "role" })
            };
        }

        // clients want to access resources (aka scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {
                // resource owner password grant client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "ro.client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = { "api1","roles" }
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

Token Sample

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImU0ZjczZDU5MjQ2YjVjMmFjOWVkNDI2ZGU4YzlhNGM2IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NDYyNTk0NTYsImV4cCI6MTU0NjI2MzA1NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcGkxIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InJvLmNsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6IjIiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NDYyNTk0NTYsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicm9sZXMiLCJhcGkxIl0sImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.D6OvbrGx2LwrYSySne59VJ_-_kZ-WriNUbDiETiHO4pknYJzBxKr307DxvBImlvP8w35Cxj3rKxwyWDqVxyhdFhFvFFuHmxqIAv_g2r37lYj3ExcGYAn23Q1i4PuXXBWQe2AHuwFsN2cfPcG39f-N-q7pfLFhoHacXe8vSWyvKxSD0Vj3qVz15cj5VMV1R8qhodXMO-5sZfY1wNfkcJmqmXnbpPnUK_KKUY1Pi6YJkU1nYRXGRoW7YLXc7Y2SFSfa9c1ubU3DDVJV0JqVxSBpfGnvydHEpk-gBx11yQgW5nsJdu6Bi2-DVGA5AdZ_-7pz0AVI-eZPwk2lNtlivmoeA

APS.NET_USERS Table

[image]

APS.NET_USERS_Claims Table

[image]

Postman
[image]

ApiRequest
[image]

Claims While Using `[Authorize]`

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your Api, somewhere before `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")` add a line for `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`.

More info at [this post](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/).

**EDIT:**
Additionally, try to update your identity resources configuration with `roles` identity resource.

```
    // scopes define the resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResource("roles", new[] { "role" })
        };
    }
```

And your client `AllowedScopes` needs adding `roles` as well then:

```
    AllowedScopes = { "api1", "roles" }
```

Lastly, your postman request should then ask for the `roles` scope to be included   `scope: api1 roles`.

**EDIT 2:**
Also, update your profile to include roles in the issued claims:

```
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.Claims);

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }
```

The above should probably be updated to only add `roles` claim when it is requested.

Make sure your newly issued JWT tokens now include `roles` claim like the one in below:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImU0ZjczZDU5MjQ2YjVjMmFjOWVkNDI2ZGU4YzlhNGM2IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NDY0Mzk0MTIsImV4cCI6MTU0NjQ0MzAxMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcGkxIiwicm9sZXMiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoicm8uY2xpZW50Iiwic3ViIjoiMiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU0NjQzOTQxMSwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJyb2xlIjpbIkFkbWluIiwiU3R1ZGVudCJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJhcGkxIiwicm9sZXMiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.irLmhkyCTQB77hm3XczL4krGMUqAH8izllG7FmQhZIQaYRqI7smLIfrqd6UBDFWTDpD9q0Xx0oefUzjBrwq2XnhGSm83vxlZXaKfb0RdLbYKtC4BlypgTEj8OC-G0ktPqoN1C0lh2_Y2PfKyQYieSRlEXkOHeK6VWfpYKURx6bl33EVDcwe_bxPO1K4axdudtORpZ_4OOkx9b_HvreYaCkuUqzUzrNhYUMl028fPFwjRjMmZTmlDJDPu3Wz-jTaSZ9CHxELG5qIzmpbujCVknh3I0QxRU8bSti2bk7Q139zaiPP2vT5RWAqwnhIeuY9xZb_PnUsjBaxyRVQZ0vTPjQ

Comment: Thanks, I added ```JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();``` but not working...

Comment: @Oli Ok, can you share the a sample of the token that gets generated by idsrv4 (like one in your first screenshot, but in plain text). Additionally, can you try to leave `[Authorize]` attribute only which you said works and then in the debugger inspect ClaimsPrincipal to see what claims are actually there?

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, I think we're close to solving this. Can you add `roles` to the request scope in your Postman request, so should be `api1 roles`.

Comment: I added roles still not working. codes, token and last pictures updated please check it out. Thanks

Comment: Ok, the last thing that is left uncertain are the users. Can you share the snapshot of your users? Can you share where it says that your users have particular roles?

Comment: Can you also add `openid` to the request scope in your Postman request so that it has `api1 openid roles`? And add `openid` to `AllowedScopes` for the client.

Comment: @Oli Ok, you have custom ProfileService maybe? Can you debug and see if it’s being hit? Also do you add relevant role claims in there?

Comment: yes its hitting, sorry but i uploaded my entire solution in https://github.com/Mohammad7070/ShagerdanehIdentityServer please feel free to check it, i also put my database in root dir with db.bak name

Comment: @Oli I got it working, check the update #2 in the answer. The other parts of the answer are also still valid btw.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the claims are not added to the *access token*.

There are two tokens, the *access token* and the *identity token*.

When you want to add claims to the *identity token*, then you'll have to configure the *IdentityResource*. If you want to add claims to the *access token*, then you'll have to configure the *ApiResource* (or scope).

This should fix it for you:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API"),
        new ApiResource("roles", "My Roles", new[] { "role" })
    };
}
```

**Make sure the client (postman) requests the `roles` scope.**

I did test it with the [sample code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords) from IdentityServer. In my setup I've added the role 'TestUser' to alice:

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "1",
    Username = "alice",
    Password = "password",
    Claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("role", "TestUser") } 
},
```

The Postman call, please note the requested scope:

[image]

The access token including the role claim:

[image]

Comment: no sorry it doesn't works. i added github link to question please check

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by adding '**role**' in **Type** column in **ApiClaims** table see the image below.

**ApiResourceId** column name found in **ApiClaims** table is primary key of **ApiResources** table with **Id** column name.

[image]

Comment: As of today, this was actually all that was needed. You can put the claim type either in the `ApiClaims` table for it to be global to all scopes for the API, or you can add it to a specific scope of the API and create it under the `ApiScopeClaims` table.