# How include roleclaim to accesstoken?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I secure my API with identityserver4 and asp.net identity. The identity database has tables roles and roleclaims. For my security model I need roles with her roleclaim. I include role to access token, but I don't understand how to include roleclaim.

```
//Example of API with roles
new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
{
   UserClaims = new []{ "name", "role" }
}
```

Comment: I don't use Role claims, but just `AspNetUserClaims` in my project, you can take a look: https://github.com/Exoft/e-folio/blob/master/e-Folio/AuthConfig.cs

Comment: What is "aspnet identity"? Do you mean "ASP.NET identity"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes. I mean ASP.NET identity.

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko Looked at your project. Adding user claims is what I already know how to do. What I do not understand is how to add roleclaims from the Asp.Net model identities with asp.net identity roles.

Comment: @chichiton I think what you need   https://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims. Can you post your AuthConfig?

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko my tokens always include user claim and claim with type "role" (Roles table in asp.net identity) and i want include in token with type "roleclaim" (RoleClaims table) for user roles.

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko my project looks like this example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/8_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity I just included the roles in ApiResource. The link you gave seems to contain a solution to my problem, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976553/identityserver4-role-based-authorization-for-web-api-with-asp-net-core-identity/53977681#53977681) how to include roles in the access tokens. If you want to additionally include role claims, you will need to use `RoleManager`.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(context.Subject.Claims);

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var roleClaims = await RoleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role)); //Adds "role" claim
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims); //Adds other role claims
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx. This is what I was looking for.