# IdentityServer4 can not read all claims

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims

I use from IdentityServer4 in asp.net core 2.2.

My Get Profile Data is:

```
 public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "fullname"));

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }
```

And I added client as follow:

```
 new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientName = "Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:45876/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:45876/signout-callback-oidc" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new[] { "http://localhost:45876/" },
                AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "webapi"
                    },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
```

When I read claims in the client I have some of claims not all of theme.
NameIdentifier is null?

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

What is my problem? What should I do?

Comment: I think there may be multiple issues here. In the first place, there are two tokens and different audiences. The client uses a different mapping than the api. Also, by default Identity Resource claims are not available in either the Identity Token and Access Token. The client should contact the UserInfo endpoint to request the Identity Resource claims. For an Mvc client you can set the option `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` to include the Identity Resource claims to the access token, or include them using configuration as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976553#54004765).

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the claims to used for select values from the json user data and create Claims. This done in `OpenIdConnectOptions`:

```
services
.Authentication()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    // For map all claims
    options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Profile Service will help dynamically adding user's claims . That claims could be added into an identity token, an access token, or the user info endpoint . The constant `IdentityServerConstants.ProfileDataCallers` contains the different constant values. You can trace the logic by filtering `context.Caller` .

Concern about the length of ID Token , by default the claims won't include in ID token . You can use one of below solutions to add custom claims to client app's user claim principle :

1. In client app , you can set `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true` in OpenID connect options ,so that client app will send a request to OIDC's userinfo endpoint to get the extra claims , then you can use `ClaimActions.MapJsonKey` map the claim to user claims/cookie :

   ```
   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
   options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   ```
2. Another solution is set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to `true` when registering client in Identity Server , so that custom claims will add to id token , and client app will directly map claims from ID token to user claim principle :

   ```
   AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken =true
   ```