# How do I store an OWIN OAuth 2 access_token in an HttpOnly Secure cookie?

Tags: security, cookies, oauth-2.0, owin, bearer-token

My primary goal is to properly secure a series of Web API controllers. Thus far, I have used OWIN to generate access_tokens and tested the functionality by decorating a class with [Authorize], then calling it with jQuery ajax calls containing a Bearer token in the header. It seems the right path, but I've read local storage is not secure. Rather, a cookie marked as HttpOnly and Secure seems the favored solution.

I've been able to find mentions that people are utilizing local storage, and even a walk through:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

What I have not been able to find is how to configure OWIN to use cookies to store tokens.

Answer (score 0):

**SERVER SIDE ARCHITECTURE**

The OWIN stack will tie you to cookie based security and works like this. It may be that this is a perfect fit for your requirements:

- Web UI makes an Ajax call to a web back end and implicitly sends an auth cookie
- Web UI is limited to calling a web back end in the same domain
- Web back end gets access token from cookie
- Web back end forwards the access token to an API in a different domain
- API validates access token

A common approach is demonstrated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274473/identity-server-add-claims-to-access-token-in-hybrid-flow-in-mvc-client), where tokens are included in the auth cookie, and the web back end unpacks cookies from tokens.

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);

id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
```

**REQUIREMENTS?**

I would always recommend starting with goals / requirements rather than technology from vendors such as Microsoft, which is often a little old or suboptimal.

**CLIENT SIDE ARCHITECTURE**

If you want to do more on the client side, then an alternative approach is to use an SPA architecture and do more in Javascript:

- Use a library such as [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)
- Send access tokens directly to cross domain APIs
- Consider storing tokens only in browser memory rather than in local storage

If interested in this approach in terms of your future planning, then these 2 posts of mine are a good starting point:

- [Web Architecture Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-spas/)
- [Initial Tutorial and Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/).

Anyway, if any of this is useful, feel free to post follow up questions.